# How to use Spring @Value annotation to set values?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I recently started learning Spring core framework. I feel confident using spring with XML but wanted to try only annotation-based programs but now I am stuck on this @Value annotation.

I have a class Line extending Shape interface which uses the Point object as a dependency. The Point object has two ints x and y which I am trying to set values using @Value but on running the program the values always come as null.
I have tried making a lot of changes in driver class or appconfig but still not getting it.

Point.class

```
    @Component
    public class Point {
    @Value("10")
    int x;
    @Value("20")
    int y;      
        
    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }       
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }       
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }       
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Point [x=" + x + ", y=" + y + "]";
    }   
}
```

Line.class

```
@Component
public class Line implements Shape {
    private int size;
    private String type;
    @Autowired
    Point pointA;  
    @Autowired
    Point pointB;       
    
    public Line() {
    }
    public Line(int size, String type, Point pointA, Point pointB) {
        super();
        this.size = size;
        this.type = type;
        this.pointA = pointA;
        this.pointB = pointB;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Triangle [size=" + size + ", type=" + type + ", pointA=" + pointA + ", pointB=" + pointB + "]";
    }

    /*
         getters and setters.....
    */
}
```

ApplicationConfig.class

```
    @ComponentScan
    @Configuration
    public class ApplicationConfig {    
          
          @Bean 
          public Line line() { return new Line(); }
          
          @Bean 
          public Point point() { return new Point(); }   
         
    }
```

DrawingApp.class

```
public class DrawingApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
                
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationConfig.class); 

        Shape line = context.getBean(Line.class);
        System.out.println(line);
        
    }
```

My output is always like this even though i have set values of x & y as 10 and 20 respectively:

```
Line [size=0, type=null, pointA=Point [x=0, y=0], pointB=Point [x=0, y=0]]
```

How can I set the values of the point object Using annotations?

Comment: *"I feel confident using spring with XML"* ... you shouldn't. Using XML for Spring is a thing of the past.

Comment: The [`@Value`  annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) is used to pull a value from another source, e.g. `application.yml`. If you want to assing a constant value, just set the fields to that value or create a bean producer method that creattes a bean with this specific values.

Comment: (1) Use constructors rather than field injection whenever possible. (2) Autowiring is for _application structure_ and should be used for service objects but not value objects like `Point`.

Answer (score 5):

[**@Value**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html)

> Annotation used at the field or method/constructor parameter level
> that indicates a default value expression for the annotated element.
> Typically used for expression-driven or property-driven dependency
> injection. Also supported for dynamic resolution of handler method
> arguments — for example, in Spring MVC.
>
> A common use case is to inject values using #{systemProperties.myProp}
> style SpEL (Spring Expression Language) expressions. Alternatively,
>
> The actual value expression such as #{systemProperties.myProp} or property placeholder > such as ${my.app.myProp}.

**Usage**

You can define the value of your property using the application.properties or application.yml and you can access the value using the `@Value`

**application.properties**

```
point.x = 10
point.y = 20
```

Access value using the `@Value` as below

```
@Value("${point.x}")
private String x;

@Value("${point.y}")
private String y;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it is not a good practice to use harcoded values within the code block. You may provide it as an external source to your software/application.

The value you determine in `@Value` annotation is supposed to be obtained from another source, e.g., application.yml . However, you can hardcode a desired value as well, but as a fallback default value against the external source.

```
@Value("${point.x:12}")
private int x;
@Value("${point.y:14}")
private int y;
```

Here, if you provide the external source, it will have precedence over the hardcoded default value!